# Does Laravel Audit Works for Mass Insertion

Tags: laravel, laravel-auditing

Laravel Audit APplied on My project is working for single insertion, update delete etc,
but when doing Mass insert, its not Auditing, Does Laravel audit works for Mass insert / delete?

Comment: Model events do not fire on bulk operations. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events

Comment: @DigitalDrifter  So that means, Audit won't work in case of mass CRUD operation, am I right, we need to manually call audit package and update data in such cases , right!